What do we call reading aloud parts of words?
What do we call speaking/reading/pronouncing a word or a part of a word of a paragraph by several people?
For example, "Doctor Paige will be here right after lunch to see her."
Suppose there are ten people and each one reads a part of a word like this:
Person 1 : doc
Person 2 : tor
Person 3 : pai
Person 4 : ge
Person 5 ......

I don't think we have a specific name for this sort of game/speaking style. In classrooms, I've heard of "popcorn reading" where one person reads a few sentences and then calls somebody else who has to start reading from there. (It's intended to make sure every child is following along because at any moment they might have to start reading). There's a game called "1 word stories" where people take turns adding one word at a time and trying to tell a coherent story.

Paige is monosyllabic, BTW.

@Kaia they have used this in some movies like bumble bee in transformers and another movie i dont remember its title it was a video message with all us presidents .

@Tintin Yeah, I've seen the thing you're talking about, but I don't think there's an exact term for it--if you were writing a script, you'd just describe it. "Each character says one syllable, together forming the complete sentence"

@Kaia do you know the title of the movie using us presidents caracter?

What leads you to suppose that there might be a word that names this practice.  Or, to put the question more colloquially, what makes you think that that is even a thing?

I.Breaking words into syllables.

What do we call speaking/ reading/ pronouncing a word or a part of a word of a paragraph by several people?

When a word is broken into syllables it is called
1.syllabication or syllabification.
2.chunking.
The same words can be used if it is played as a game. The purpose is both understanding the pronunciation and remembering some information..

Segmenting spoken words into syllables is the most simple phonological awareness skill for most children. It involves breaking words into chunks or beats and each beat will contain a vowel sound, for example, the word ‘big’ contains one syllable, ‘fish/ing’ contains two syllables, and ‘hip/po/pot/a/mus’ contains five..
https://fivefromfive.com.au/phonemic-awareness/segmenting-words-into-syllables/#:~:text=Segmenting%20spoken%20words%20into%20syllables,a%2Fmus'%20contains%20five.

II. Word meanings.
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

syllabication or syllabification.
1.the division of written or spoken words into syllables, or the combination of sounds or letters to form syllables:
2.an example of a syllable being formed, or of a word being divided into syllables:
Example
While syllabication may help students to access the pronunciation of words, it does not help them to access meanings.
.
chunking.
noun [ U ]
a way of dealing with or remembering information by separating it into small groups or chunks:


That type of speech exercise or game is not chunking. A chunk, in language teaching, are  groups of words that are taught to students, it's a type of mnemonic device, in its simplest form: "drive a car" or more complex "Give me [gimme] back my money". A single sound or syllable is not a small group.

@Mari-LouA I think OP is looking for a word for breaking a word into syllables. You are right about chunking but some sites I saw it is used also for breaking a word or a mobile number into chunks. (link in my answer)..

A mobile number in chunks would be "039" (O three nine) "double 7" (77), "202" (two O two) etc. instead of reading the number in single digits. In the UK and the US numbers are often cited one by one, in Italy they are sometimes read as units so "two O two" will be read as one word duecentodue (two hundred and two)
